# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: oracle11g, visual-studio-2017

I tried to integrate the oracle 11g database with Visual Studio 2017.

However, table creation is not possible due to the following error. There were many solutions on google, but none of those helped me. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Use a database you know how to connect to.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. In our assignment we can only use the oracle 11g database.